# iOS: Universal App - Release as iPhone only

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, universal-binary, build-settings

A customer is interested in releasing a universal app. However, the first release will contain only the iPhone version, the second release will contain both versions.

I found a few links where ppl figured out how to make this work in the simulation environment. However, i could not find claims about apps that finally were released to the AppStore successfully. I need verification of this.

Do you have links of people claiming to have universal apps released for iphone only or did you do it yourself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not possible to only release the iPhone version via iTunes Connect, but you can set the Target Device to iPhone-only for the first version and it'll only be released for iPhone/iPod touch.

Comment: can you confirm that you have released an application with this solution or do you know someone who did?

Comment: Well, yes, I can. Should note that it's the same solution as Mitesh posted, but yes, all developers who updated their app when iPad came out would've done this. Not specifically limited the app to iPhone previously, but then it was the only option, essentially the same thing.

Comment: If you wanted to confirm this just try to run it on the iPad simulator. It should run the iPhone version.

Comment: i did confirm it via Simulator, but had also to verify that the solution really goes to the store like described

Comment: okay, i changed the targeted device family to be iPhone only, but when the app runs on the iPad (i see the frame of the iPhone only apps) but the app crashes because it loads from the iPad app delegate which has a UISplitViewController that crashes in loading .. i want to direct the app to run the app delegate of the iPhone instead even if its running on iPad device/simulator

Answer (score 27):

In the application's `Build Settings` change the `Targeted Device Family` to iPhone, instead of iPhone/iPad.

[image: Targeted Device Family]

In the latest xcode you can do this by summary screen too.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: thank you, can you confirm that you have released an application with this solution or do you know someone who did?

Answer (score 9):

You need to make two changes. First, Set the *Target Device Family* back to iPhone. Second, in the info plist remove the *Main nib file base name (iPad)* entry. If you don't do that last step it will run as though it was an iPhone app (small view port with 2x button) but your iPad main window and delegate will be triggered.

Here is a more details post with some images for illustration:
http://www.fullboarcreative.com/labs/2012/04/20/tip-going-from-a-universal-to-single-device-app/