# What will happen if we update an existing iPhone app to support iPads?

Tags: ios, app-store

If we have an application that is currently live on the App Store, compatible with only iPhone devices, and we make an update compatible with both iPhone and iPad devices (Universal) what will happen?

I can think of two possibilities:

- the app will not be updated - the updates will require app binaries only for iPhone devices;
- there is no problem in adding the iPad support.

I did not see a clear answer in Apple's Guides. There were some discussions in the links below:  
[iOS Universal App question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303324/ios-universal-app-question) 
[iPhone/iPad - Breaking universal into iPhone app only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654646/iphone-ipad-breaking-universal-into-iphone-app-only) 
[iOS: Universal App - Release as iPhone only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868034/ios-universal-app-release-as-iphone-only)

Does anyone have the answer, with references to Apple Guides? I need to be sure this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second answer: it's absolutely not a problem. Those who downloaded your app on an iPad and run in "iPhone simulator" mode on their iPad, will be happily pleased to see they now have a full-fledged app. Users on an iPhone won't notice a difference.

Edit:

Closest I can find in Apple's doc is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

It states that "The following sections highlight the changes you must make to an existing app to ensure that it runs smoothly on any type of device": essentially, update the info.plist and rework your view and view controllers.

Comment: Is this answer based on previous experiences or you can relate to Apple Guide's notes? Thank you.

Comment: It's based on a real application I updated something like 18 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad will happen if that's what you're asking. Your iPhone users will only notice a difference in the apps file size (if they notice anything at all). And iPad users will notice that your app now takes up their full screen.

There is nothing in the submission or approval process that will stop you from doing this. As long as you've configured everything correctly iPhone-only to universal will be a smooth transition.

Comment: Do you have a previous experience with this kind of updates? Is this explained in Apple's Guide? I need to make sure. Thank you.

Comment: @Radu I've never seen any documentation on this, but I have done it myself. It is very cut and dry. Updating from iPhone only to a universal app won't cause any issues for you or your users.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I will wait for more answers to make sure - as I said in my question, need some Guide references where this issue is covered.

Comment: @Radu Here's a link to a pretty good article on the subject: http://www.philmetcalfe.com/ios-updating-a-single-application-to-a-universal-application/